# Grafana Alert when "no data"

Tags: alert, grafana

I have an Grafana alert that fails sometimes for "No Data".  Does this setting fail when it first detects No Data or does it go to Pending state and try up to the 30m interval that I have set?  I feel like it throws the alert when it first detects No Data.

If the above is true, is it possible to have it check multiple times before alerting?